# How to get the "Assertion failure message"in this plugin"Flexible File Writer"

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I know in the "Result Save configuration Sample", but I want to get it in the "File Writer Fixible", I don't know how to get it?

Thanks in advance!

@dmitri t  I tried to modify the beanshellAssertion and got a response , but still do not understand how to set up user properties in and get the parameters in the Flexible File Writer .

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ET8C.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eoto9.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend doing the following:

1. Use [Beanshell Listener](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_Listener) to extract assertion failure messages into JMeter Variables. Example code will look like:

   ```
   import org.apache.jmeter.assertions.AssertionResult;

   for (int i = 0; i < sampleResult.getAssertionResults().length; i++) {
       AssertionResult assertionResult = sampleResult.getAssertionResults()[i];
       vars.put("assertionResult_" + i, assertionResult.getFailureMessage());
   }
   ```

   it will produce variables like:

   ```
   assertionResult_0=Test failed: text expected to contain /foo/
   assertionResult_1=The operation lasted too long: It took 1,010 milliseconds, but should not have lasted longer than 500 milliseconds.
   etc.
   ```
2. Use [sample_variables](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html#sample_variables) property (by the way, it is mentioned in FlexibleFileWriter [documentation](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/FlexibleFileWriter/#Saving-JMeter-Variables-with-Flexible-File-Writer)) to configure JMeter to store generated variables in results file. Add the following line to *user.properties* file (lives under /bin folder of your JMeter installation)

   ```
   sample_variables=assertionResult0,assertionResult1,etc.
   ```

   after JMeter restart `assertionResult0` and other variables values will be added to JMeter .jtl results file.

See [How to Use BeanShell: JMeter's Favorite Built-in Component](https://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) guide for more information on what else can be done with the help of Beanshell scripting in your JMeter test.

Comment: HI @Dmitri T I tried to modify the beanshellAssertion and got a response , but still do not understand how to set up user properties in and get the parameters in the Flexible File Writer（Reference topics image）:)

Comment: my example assumes beanshell **listener**, not assertion. You won't be able to store JMeter variables via flexible file writer, use `sample_variables` approach.

Comment: HI @dmitri, After debugging , flexible plug-in can save assertion!example: the user properties file set "sample_variables = assertionResult_0" and then set the FIX in "| variable # 0 |" so that you can be saved to the specified text in assertionMessage extremely grateful for your advice !